Webworker not appearing in code coverage report in angular
I've wrote a test for a web worker in angular and it run properly.
The problem is it not appearing in the code coverage report generated after the run.
this is the code i'm testing:
/// <reference lib="webworker" />

let timer: number;
let currentInterval: number;
let _inactivityTime: number;
const ONE_SECOND = 1000;

const startTimer = (inactivityTime: number) => {
  _inactivityTime = inactivityTime;
  timer = inactivityTime;
  currentInterval = setInterval(() => {
    timer--;
    if (timer <= 0) {
      clearInterval(currentInterval);
      postMessage('logout');
    }
  }, ONE_SECOND) as unknown as number;
};

And this is my test.
describe('Timeout worker', () => {
  it('should send logout message after the time has expired', (done) => {
    const worker = new Worker(new URL('./app.worker', import.meta.url));
    worker.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
      expect(event.data).toBe('logout');
      done();
    });
    jasmine.clock().install();
    worker.postMessage({ action: 'start', time: 0 });
    jasmine.clock().tick(2001);
    jasmine.clock().uninstall();
  });
});

I've tried to explicitly declare it in the karma.conf file with no success.

Hello, have you figured this out? Nowadays I have been struggling with the same issue.

hey @aekber i have no luck doing this... test is made, it can fail and pass as usual but do not appear in code coverage
